# synthetic multi-node crossbar system implementation

Tags: crossbar

I am implementing a system composed of a collection of small systems, ie. Raspberry, Yun, Beaglebone, the occasional PC.  Crossbar.io has real promise ... but, as I understand it, doesn't currently support multiple nodes.  Am I correct?  Does anyone know when that might happen?

In the meantime it occurred to me that each individual node can offer an http interface that I might be able to use for my purposes.  My initial thought is to crate workers that wrap access to the web the interface on subsidiary nodes.  This fits the overall architecture of the system I want to create - does it have any merit?  Is it tractable?  I'm new to websockets - and insight would be a great help.

Thanks for your time,
Al

Answer (score 0):

In general that does sound like a fit for Crossbar.io.

There is no timeline on multi-node (i.e. multiple routers), but we hope to have at least hot-standby nodes for high availability ready in Q1. Other than for high availability, I think that a single instance should provide sufficient performance for most applications out there - on a single current (non-high-end) Xeon we're talking tens of thousands of events a second, and concurrent connections are mostly limited by RAM (and 100s of thousands on a single box are definitely not a problem). (If you need more than that then I'd be very interested in your specific use case - we want to learn more about our users.)

I don't completely understand the second part of your question: What precisely is the architecture you're planning here? If you're talking about the integrated Web server, then with recent optimizations (it can now use multiple cores) this should be enough for even moderately big sites, and with SPAs you're not likely to ever run into performance issues.

Hope this helps, and I'll be glad to answer in more detail once you've clarified the second part.

Comment: The architecture I want to implement is aimed at a different application space.  I wish to implement systems that are aggregations of small nodes.  Take, for instance, the instance of building a test system for power supplies.  Typically I would need at least a calibrated scope, oscilloscope, and some kind of load; I need to control and orchestrate these components to carry out either canned or ad hoc tests.  Since all of these bits expose an interface for computer control I could build an application on a PC.

Comment: ... continued
What I propose is to front-end each of these components with small system (Pi, Raspberry, Beaglebone, the choice grows each day) that presents an interface that is an abstracted view of the attached component.  With these nodes I would them build my test system as a cooperating collection of nodes rather than a PC application.  Why?  First, I can charatarize a node in terms of capability rather than the physical device attached to it; so I can use any scope in the building rather a particular brand.

Comment: (continued)
Beyond this I can construct other test systems from the same nodes in a different configuration; I don't need to write a new application.  In short I am looking at a composition rather then bandwidth problem but I think distributed routers under crossbar would do the job.  Thus the thrust of my question.

I am still in the early stages and I hope I've managed to convey what I'm looking for.  Any comments, thoughts, ideas more than welcome - at the moment I spend a lot of time talking to myself.

Al

Comment: In the above 'calibrated scope' == 'calibrated supply'

Comment: I see your use case more clearly now. Could we take this to the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/crossbario), since that is a better forum for back-and-forth discussions?

Comment: Fine by me - I will mosey over to the url you provided.  I assume I can find you there?

Comment: I now have an account on the forum.  I propose to create a topic that is  an edited version of this conversation - OK by you?